# gradle duplicate value resource 'attr/highlightColor' with config "

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHtRU.png)

App build.gradle -> http://dpaste.com/009PRJZ

project gradle -> http://dpaste.com/1N1H5CF

Aapt error log -> http://dpaste.com/1FJKPWT

values.xml - http://dpaste.com/0GAQS23
values from merged.dir -> http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=16583979994115563507

I have been trying to fix for hours please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is skim over the merged values.xml file from the error message and figure out the view that is causing conflict and exclude it from ever making it to the gradle build phase. Stackoverflow :( And Android studio could be better :|

Answer (score 0):

Meh, it was a bad question, i was just burnt then. Programmers should get used to rests :)